# Trying to parse HTML with help of PHP, but no result

Tags: php, expression

I'm parsing HTML file for specific strings, but my result is empty arrays. I'm using regular expression for this, here it is - `/(?<=alt\=\")([А-Яа-я]+\s?[А-Яа-я]+)(?=\"\ssrc)/i`

I'm searching for the Cyrillic symbols. Here is a piece of code which I parse:

```
 <div id="s71" style="position:absolute; left:381px; top:95px; height: 9px;">
            <img id="imm4" alt="Алексеевская" src="/img/obana4.gif" style="cursor:hand; cursor:pointer; position: absolute;">
            <div class="border_round" onclick="JavaScript:mSel(4);" style="width: 67px; height: 9px; cursor:hand; cursor:pointer; position: absolute; top: 0px;"><img style="position: absolute;" src="/img/blank.gif" width="67" height="9" alt=""></div>
        </div>
        <div id="s123" style="position:absolute; left:292px; top:45px; height: 9px;">
            <img id="imm5" alt="Алтуфьево" src="/img/obana4.gif" style="cursor:hand; cursor:pointer; position: absolute;">
            <div class="border_round" onclick="JavaScript:mSel(5);" style="width: 54px; height: 9px; cursor:hand; cursor:pointer; position: absolute; top: 0px;"><img style="position: absolute;" src="/img/blank.gif" width="54" height="9" alt=""></div>
        </div>
```

Sorry, forget to add the PHP code. Here is my code below:

```
//opening and read file which contains code to parse
$hndl = fopen("./metro.html","r");
$size =  filesize("./metro.html");      
$result = fread($hndl,$size);
fclose($hndl);
unset($hndl);


//trying to parse code with expression
$metro_mask = '/(?<=alt\=\")([А-Яа-я]+\s?[А-Яа-я]+)(?=\"\ssrc)/i';
$output = array();
preg_match_all($metro_mask,$result,$output); 
var_dump($output);
```

it otputs this:

`array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  1 => 
    array (size=0)
      empty`

i've also tried to do this:

```
$hndl = fopen("./metro.html","r");      
$size =  filesize("./metro.html"); 
$result = fread($hndl,$size);       
fclose($hndl);      
unset($hndl);               

$html = new DOMDocument();          
$html->loadHTML($result);                   
$links = array();               
foreach($html->getElementsByTagName('a') as $link) {            
echo $link->getAttribute('href');       
}
```

but have null as result. where do i wrong?

AND FINALLY! I solved this problem with regular expression. All that I were need is this:

```
/(?<=alt\=\")\S+?\s?\S+?(?=\")/s
```

It gaved me a result:

```
array (size=1)
  0 => 
    array (size=184)
      0 => string 'Авиамоторная' (length=24)
      1 => string 'Автозаводская' (length=26)
      2 => string 'Академическая' (length=26)
      3 => string 'Александровский сад' (length=37)
      4 => string 'Алексеевская' (length=24)
      5 => string 'Алтуфьево' (length=18)
      6 => string 'Аннино' (length=12)
      7 => string 'Арбатская' (length=18)
      8 => string 'Арбатская' (length=18)
```

Before I live, I want to say, like our Russian people say: "терпение и труд - все перетрут" ))

Comment: Please provide further relevant PHP. Just providing regex details is nowhere near enough for us to go on.

Comment: Do not parse HTML with regular expressions. It will never, ever work correctly. Just use some regular HTML parser instead and end your misery with it.

Comment: @jsalonen Well... sometimes regex works... If you only need all `href` attr, regex is perfect. Anything more, not so much.

Comment: have you tried if your regex works (for example at regexr.com?)

Comment: @jsalonen But how can I grab the necessary string then?

Comment: @Luke I have tried it on the  http://regex101.com/ And it worked well! It just doesn't work with PHP

Comment: Why would you ever want to use regexps for HTML parsing when you can just use a library like http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/ and do the job flawlessly with less code?

Comment: PHP has `DOMDocument::loadHTML` which might even be enough.

Comment: @jsalonen Because I have never tried )) Nice tip, will test immediately!

Comment: @user3677363 Start using now, never turn back or regret!

Comment: I'd suggest you to edit your question or add it to a new question. Its very hard to follow from a comment.

Comment: @jasolnen sorry, now it's done